# Why is my page not returning data from an API call despite it being asynchronised and despite the page rendering only after the function returns?

Tags: javascript, api, express, asynchronous

In the below code, I call the getLondonUsers() function, which is async, and then after it is fulfilled I render the page. However the page does not render with the returned data from the API call. Instead it is blank due to the call returning 'undefined' since it doesn't seem to wait for the function call to return before rendering. Why is this?

```
    var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var router = express.Router();


var options = {
  'method': 'GET',
  'url': 'https://bpdts-test-app.herokuapp.com/city/London/users',
  'headers': {
    'accept': 'application/json'
  }};


/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
     getLondonUsers().then( londonUsers => res.render("index", {title: londonUsers}));
});

 async function getLondonUsers(){
  request(options, function (error, response) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    console.log(response.body);
    return response.body;
  });



}

module.exports = router;
```

Console.log() shows what is meant to be rendered below:

```
[{"id": 135, "first_name": "Mechelle", "last_name": "Boam", "email": "mboam3q@thetimes.co.uk", "ip_address": "113.71.242.187", "latitude": -6.5115909, "longitude": 105.652983}, {"id": 396, "first_name": "Terry", "last_name": "Stowgill", "email": "tstowgillaz@webeden.co.uk", "ip_address": "143.190.50.240", "latitude": -6.7098551, "longitude": 111.3479498}, {"id": 520, "first_name": "Andrew", "last_name": "Seabrocke", "email": "aseabrockeef@indiegogo.com", "ip_address": "28.146.197.176", "latitude": "27.69417", "longitude": "109.73583"}, {"id": 658, "first_name": "Stephen", "last_name": "Mapstone", "email": "smapstonei9@bandcamp.com", "ip_address": "187.79.141.124", "latitude": -8.1844859, "longitude": 113.6680747}, {"id": 688, "first_name": "Tiffi", "last_name": "Colbertson", "email": "tcolbertsonj3@vimeo.com", "ip_address": "141.49.93.0", "latitude": 37.13, "longitude": -84.08}, {"id": 794, "first_name": "Katee", "last_name": "Gopsall", "email": "kgopsallm1@cam.ac.uk", "ip_address": "203.138.133.164", "latitude": 5.7204203, "longitude": 10.901604}]
```

.jade file:

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= 'Here are all the users within a 50 mile radius of London:'
  p  #{londonUsers}
```